Google Cloud Functions v2 deploy always fails to clean up
I have created a brand new Node.js 20 v2 GCP Cloud Function project.
Every time I deploy I get the error message below:
> $ firebase deploy --only "functions:triggerCacheRebuildv2"

=== Deploying to 'my-project-api2'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at
        https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/my-api2/eu/gcf
        https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/my-api2/us/gcf

✔  Deploy complete!

How can this be avoided?
It is cumbersome to clean the image after every deploy.

So, did you follow the advice of the error message and "attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually"?  Does that not resolve the issue permanently?  If it doesn't, then you should reach out to Firebase support for personalized assistance.  There should be no requirement to manually delete anything.

Redeploying does not work, sadly. I have to delete them manually after each deploy to be able to deploy again. Will reach out to Firebase support. Thanks!
